# RabbitMQ suddenly stopped working in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I'm getting this error while running docker-compose up

```
{error,"Cookie file /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie must be accessible by owner only",[{auth,init_cookie,0,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,286}]},{auth,init,1 [{file,"auth.erl"},{line,140}]},{gen_server,init_it,2,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,365}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,333}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_    ancestors:     message_queue_len:     messages:     links:     dictionary:     trap_exit:     status:     heap_size: apply,3,[ 
{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}
rabbitmq       | [net_sup,kernel_sup,<0.36.0>]
rabbitmq       | 0
```

Everything worker fine yesterday and I didn't change anything in the docker-compose file, here it is:

```
version: '3'
services:

  rabbitmq:
    container_name: rabbitmq
    image: rabbitmq:management
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    volumes:
    - ./data:/var/lib/rabbitmq:rw
    - ./definitions.json:/opt/definitions.json:ro
    - ./rabbitmq.config:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config:ro

  votingapi:
    container_name: votingapi
    build: ./
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

  votingfront:
    container_name: votingfront
    build: ../ng-catsvdogs
    depends_on:
      - resultsapi
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"

  mysql-dev:
    image: mysql:8.0.2
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: votingdb
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  worker:
    container_name: worker
    build: ../worker-catsvdogs
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"

  resultsapi:
    container_name: resultsapi
    build: ../resultsApi-catsvdogs
    depends_on:
      - mysql-dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

I tried removing the ":rw", tried using ":ro" but nothing works, I'm stuck. Does anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should map:
 `/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia` instead of `/var/lib/rabbitmq`.

This should fix the issue

Comment: Huh.. it did work, thanks. But it worked the old way for like 2 weeks, weird :D Thank you anyway!